# On obtaining vertical asymptote using limits

Tags: algebra-precalculus, limits, functions

**Prologue**: 
I am currently enrolled for a precalculus course. While know how to evaluate vertical asymptotes by equating the denominator to $0$, I thought of trying something else.

I have a rational function $$y= \frac{3x-1}{x+5}$$

So my Hypothesis is that solving for a in this limit should give the vertical asymptote

$$\lim_{x \to a}  \frac{3x-1}{x+5} - a = 0$$

Solving this I obtain $a(x-3) =0$.

Which gives $a = 0$ or $x=3$.

Note: Actual vertical asymptote occurs at $x= -5$.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Forgive for the editing.

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: Thanks a lot . .

Comment: Well can you answer? Views are welcome :)

Comment: Your mistake is that $\lim_{x\to a} f(x) -a =0$ does not mean $x=a$ is an vertical asymptote. The question is, why would it? (That $f(a)=a$ would just means that the graph of $f$ would crosse the graph of $y=x$ at point $(a,a)$).

Comment: Well i am learning calculus,mistakes happen. :(

Comment: Well you are right, for x= -3, y can take any value since its a line parallell to y axis . This method would work for finding vertical asymptotes.

Comment: ***horizontal***

Answer (score 1):

The limit statement that you've written, $\lim\limits_{x\to a} f(x) - a =0$, is equivalent to:

$$\lim\limits_{x\to a} f(x) = a$$

That statement says that the graph of $f$ gets very close to the point $(a,a)$, which does not happen in the case of a vertical asymptote at $a$. The usual way to express a vertical asymptote using limits is:

$$\lim\limits_{x\to a} f(x) = \infty$$

The best way to find it is simply to note where the denominator approaches $0$, as you stated initially.

Answer (score 1):

$x=a $ is the equation of a vertical asymptote of the function $x\mapsto f (x) $ if
$$\lim_{x\to a}f (x)=\infty .$$

in your example,

$$\lim_{x\to -5}\frac {3x-1}{x+5}=\infty $$
thus the vertical asymptote equation is
$$x=-5$$

> or

$$\frac {3x-1}{x+5}=3-\frac {16}{x+5} $$
from here, $x=-5$ is the equation of vertical asymptote.

Comment: Yes but what you have written implies that "you already knew x=-5 is a vertical asymptote" . I  more interested in finding "a" using limits.

Comment: "I *am more" not " I more" . There has been a typing error

Comment: The limit from below is $\infty$, but the limit from above is $-\infty$.

Comment: When you find the value of *a*, haven't you already found the vertical asymptote? It seems as though this only works if you already know the value of *a*, making the process redundant.

Answer (score 1):

The line $x = a$ is a vertical asymptote of the graph of the function $f$ if one or more of the following statements holds:
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x \to a+} f(x) & = \infty\\
\lim_{x \to a+} f(x) & = -\infty\\
\lim_{x \to a-} f(x) & = \infty\\
\lim_{x \to a-} f(x) & = -\infty
\end{align*}

If $x > -5$ and $x < 1/3$, the numerator is negative while the denominator is positive.  Thus, $y < 0$.  Moreover, as we approach $-5$ from the right, the denominator approaches $0$ while the numerator approaches $3(-5) - 1 = -16$, so,
$$\lim_{x \to 5+} f(x) = -\infty$$
If $x < -5$, then both the numerator and denominator are negative.  Hence, $y > 0$.  As we approach $-5$ from the left, the denominator approaches $0$ while the numerator approaches $-16$, so 
$$\lim_{x \to 5-} f(x) = \infty$$
Vertical asymptotes occur where the denominator equals zero but the numerator does not, so you can find them by setting the denominator equal to zero after canceling any common factors from the numerator and denominator.